# Проблема с JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В проекте нажал `Invalidate and restart` студия закрылась и вдруг выскочило окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перезагрузил компьютер, выскочило обьявление о том, что есть обновление для Java поставил обновление указал новый путь в `variables`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Снова перезагрузил компьютер, но все равно та же ошибка выскакивает, когда пытаюсь открыть студию

И вот не совсем понятно мне почему в последних строчках ошибки написано

> Failed to create JVM. JVM Path: C:\Program Files\Android\AndroidStudio3.3\jre\jre

Почему студия пытается получить JVM по этому пути если в `system variable` указан вот этот путь `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161` для java

Так же странно, что студия 3.2.1 работает, а 3.3.1 нет

Что делаю не так?

**ПРАВКА**

Только, что переустановил студию, та же ошибка

**ПРАВКА**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переменная окружения JAVA_HOME должна указывать на каталоге не JRE, а JDK.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я пробовал и так и так. Результат тот же. Исправил вопрос

Comment: Она ведь у Вас просила x64, а Вы x86 подсовываете. Зайдите в папку студии и попробуйте запустить соответствующий Вашей системе файл (`studio.exe` или `studio64.exe`). Студия приносит с собой копию OpenJDK на которую ориентировались при разработке, по этому она и ищет её у себя в папке. Может слетела установка или настройка какая. Но я не припомню где указан путь к JDK

Comment: @woesss я и так пробовал. Исправил вопрос. Запустил студию прошлой версии все работает... Наверное, что то все же с настройками, а не с джавой

Comment: @woesss только, что переустановил студию, но это не помогло. Странно студия 3.2.1 работает , а 3.3.1 нет

Comment: Попробуйте временно переименовать/переместить папку `.AndroidStudio3.3` в папке пользователя (`C:\Users\<username>`). Или удалить сразу, если у Вас не было никаких особенных настроек.

Comment: @woesss не... Переименовал, переместил - не помогло... Не понял, только что вы имели ввиду `или удалить сразу` ...

Comment: есть решение простое - установка убунту

Comment: @Санаев ))) что еще? В доме не открывается окно - взорвать дом?)))

Comment: А если JAVA_HOME вообще удалить? На Вин7 и так работает.

Comment: @Эникейщик удалил, студия 3.2 продолжает работать 3.3 без изменений. Не работает

Comment: Та же самая ошибка?

Comment: @Эникейщик да...

Comment: А настройки из 3.2.1 в 3.3.1 копировали? Что, если скопировать папку config из Users/username/.AndroidStudio3.2 в .AndroidStudio3.3 (старую папку убрать в укромное место).

Comment: @Эникейщик добавил скрин в вопрос. У меня нет папки `config` ...

Comment: Не там смотрите. Не в програмфайлс, а в профилях пользователей.

Comment: @Эникейщик ДА! еееее ))) это работает))) Я начал конкурс на англ стак, так что если ты там то напиши мне ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54649422/failed-to-create-jvm-android-studio/54882521?noredirect=1#comment96535989_54882521 я отмечу верным. И тут напиши тоже

Comment: На SO можешь сам написать :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложно сказать, почему возникает проблема. `JAVA_HOME` для работы Андроид Студии и не нужна совсем. Видимо, при установке что-то идет криво и в настройки пишется что-то не то. Копирование папки `config` из предыдущей рабочей версии `Users/username/.AndroidStudio3.2` в `.AndroidStudio3.3` решает проблему.

Возможно, проблема конкретно в файле `options/jdk.table.xml`. Т.е. можно начать с него.

Answer (score 1):

Если система не видит эту переменную, попробуй перезагрузить систему.
У меня была проблема, что я прописываю переменную и путь, а система не видит.

Answer (score 0):

Для Android Studio 4+ нужно удалить «\studio.exe.vmoptions» или «studio64.exe.vmoptions»
По адресу

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Google\{studio version}
```